# displaying image from xml tag

Tags: iphone

**hi everybody**

I am new to iphone development. in my application i want to extract image from image tag from xml
and then display it in left of table cell  my code is

the xml tag of image is

```
<image>http://192.168.1.239/japantube/thumb/570.jpg</image>
```

now i in my code i have parse it in such form

```
 int blogEntryIndex1 = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] -1];
NSString *imgstring =[[blogEntries objectAtIndex: blogEntryIndex1] objectForKey: @"image"];
```

now the path of image is store in image string what i am going to do is to 
extract the image from path and display it in left of cell which i am trying

```
cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:imgstring];
```

when i run my application it crash down
can anybody help me out em very upset due to that error **thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

imageNamed: is used to retrieve images that are stored in your application's bundle as resources.  If you want to load an image using a url, then you will need to download the image and then use imageWithData:

To download the image and get its data, use NSURLConnection.  There is some good sample code provided by apple that will show you how to do this.

Comment: Dear chris thanks for reply can u send me some sample code
and as there any way to that with out downloading because its rss application what i am going to do as just to show the small tumbnil of image with title in left of cell.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have the image included into your app?  Or do you mean that you don't want to write the code for the downloading?